# Salvar imagem do Facebook no Banco de Dados

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sdk

Galera, eu sei que é muito simples, mas estou com dificuldades. Já vi alguns tópicos aqui, mas pra mim ainda não ficou claro de como fazer.

Eu preciso salvar a imagem do Facebook no banco de dados, fazendo *upload* dela para o banco. A informação que chega pra mim do facebook é esta:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?width=600
```

Mas, todos sabem que desta forma eu não consigo fazer *upload*. Alguém sabe como posso resolver isto? Tem alguns tópicos que já foram postados aqui, mas não postaram a solução, pelo menos pra mim não ficou bem esclarecido.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: De qual linguagem estamos falando?

Comment: Estamos falando de PHP

Answer (score 0):

Segue três alternativas:

```
copy("https://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?width=600");
```

Ou

```
fopen("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture");
```

Ou

```
file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture");
```